# How to to show τ ' is coarser than τ (i.e., every set open in τ 0 is open in τ )?

Tags: general-topology

[image]

my attempt for -----option A : Let X be Hausdorff, then if $x\ne y$ there are neighborhoods $V_x$ and $V_y$ such that $V_x \cap V_y = \emptyset$. Therefore $V_x\times V_y \cap D=\emptyset$ and the complement of $D$ is open. Now, assume that the latter is true. Then, for any point $(x,y)$, $x\ne y$, there is an open set around it that does not intersect $D$. Therefore, there are two sets $x\in V_x$ and $y\in V_y$ such that $V_x\times V_y$ doesn't intersect $D$, therefore $V_x \cap V_y = \emptyset$   ....as  X is Hausdorff since the diagonal is closed.

I don't know how to prove OPtion B and option C  pliz help  me

I would be more grate ful

thanks in advances

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A)

Let $x,y\in X$ with $x\neq y$ or equivalently $\langle x,y\rangle\in d^{-1}(\{0\})^{\complement}=d^{-1}((0,\infty))\subseteq X\times X$.

For proving that $(X,\tau)$ is Hausdorff it is enough to show that sets $U,V\in\tau$ exist with $x\in U$, $y\in V$ and $U\cap V=\varnothing$.

Here $(0,\infty)$ is open and $d$ is continuous so that $d^{-1}((0,\infty))$ is open.

Further $X\times X$ is equipped with the product topology so $U,V\in\tau$ exist with $$\langle x,y\rangle\subseteq U\times V\subseteq d^{-1}((0,\infty))$$

Then $U$ and $V$ satisfy the mentioned conditions and we are ready.

B)

To be shown is here that for every pair $B_1,B_2$ of such sets and every $y\in B_1\cap B_2$ there is a another such set $B$ with $y\in B\subseteq B_1\cap B_2$, and further that for every $y$ such a set $B$ exists with $y\in B$.

It is unclear to me whether we are dealing with a basis $\{B_{x,\epsilon}\mid\epsilon>0\}$ for some fixed $x$ or with a basis $\{B_{x,\epsilon}\mid\epsilon>0, x\in X\}$ and I will leave this to you.

C)

For fixed $x\in X$ prescribe function $f_x:X\to X\times X$ by $y\mapsto\langle x,y\rangle$. If $p_1$ and $p_2$ denote the projections then $p_1\circ f:X\to X$ is constant and $p_2\circ f=\mathsf{id}_X$. So both functions are continuous and the fact that $X\times X$ is equipped with product topology allows the conclusion that $f_x:X\to X\times X$ is continuous. Then composition $d\circ f:X\to X$ is continuous so that $(d\circ f)^{-1}([0,\epsilon))\in\tau$  for $\epsilon>0$. Now observe that: $$B(x,\epsilon)=(d\circ f)^{-1}([0,\epsilon))$$So actually it has been shown that $\tau$ contains a basis of $\tau'$. Then also $\tau'\subseteq\tau$ as was to be shown.

Comment: thanks alots@drhab

Comment: You are very welcome.

Comment: soory for late reply  actually i was waiting for henno brandsma answer  so  i didn't reply u  fast  @ drhab

Comment: No excuses are needed for that. Also I understand. I am a bit familiar with some topology, but Henno is real topologist :).